# IOS - FCM Push Notification not received from firebase console

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have a native ios application and it enabled FCM. I have uploaded certificate to firebase and added GoogleService-Info.plist to my project from appdelegate

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;

    NSLog(@"FCM deviceToken : %@", deviceToken);
}
```

> And I have received token "FCM deviceToken : <076bc1b2 31493038
>   08da0351 8d272982 d04f7171 46f6e619 31e89403 1457fc19>"

I have tried with this token in console, but it's showing failed.

[image]This is what i am getting from firebase console

Comment: Don't use APNS token, Use FCM token

Comment: Follow my tutorial incase if you don't understand: https://insights.nimblechapps.com/app-development/ios-app-development/how-to-use-firebase-to-send-notifications-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi @Anju You need to use

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken (NSData *)deviceToken{
[FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;NSString *fcmToken = [FIRMessaging messaging].FCMToken;
NSLog(@"FCM deviceToken : %@", deviceToken);
}
```

FCMtoken